# Display current path in terminal only

Tags: unix, terminal, path

I'm SSH'd into a computer, so I can't use a GUI to access the path name. Is there a way that you can see the path directly on terminal without having to use Nautilus?

Comment: Do you mean 'pwd' and 'ls' to see the workding directory and list the files?

Comment: This question could maybe be re-worded a little bit for better clarity, but this question, comment and answer together provided me exactly what I needed, so it's helpful!

Answer (score 914):

If you just want to get the information of current directory, you can type:

```
pwd
```

and you don't need to use the Nautilus, or you can use a teamviewer software to remote connect to the computer, you can get everything you want.

Comment: If somebody cared (as I did), pwd stands for **p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory [Source](https://www.quora.com/What-does-PWD-terminal-command-stand-for)

Comment: Not to confuse with password :D